# Is there a high level shape drawing API for C or C++?

Tags: c++, c, windows, drawing, shapes

I am starting a new project (Windows application), which needs a simple graphical interface.  The graphics are not the main point of the application, the algorithms behind them are, so I'd like to spend as little time as possible thinking about graphics.

I need to draw simple shapes, connect them with lines, and label both the shapes and the edges.  My ideal API would look something like

```
 n1 = Rectangle(width, height, center1);
 n1->label("Node1");
 n2 = Circle(radius, center2);
 l = Line(n1->rightEdge()->midpoint()), (n2->center()-Point(n2->radius,0));
 l->label("pathway",BELOW);
```

I know I could certainly use a low-level library to build up to this level of abstraction.  But I'd rather not, if it has already been done.  Does a graphics library with this level of abstraction exist?   I'd be equally happy with C/C++.  C# would be an option too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the general ease of writing that kind of high-level system, given a low-level drawing API, you generally don't see this kind of 2D scene graph library. The kind where there are explicit objects in the scene, and you move the objects around on the level of objects.

The closest I can think of is the way WPF handles drawing, where you create graphics objects and attach them to windows. And that's .NET only.

Everything else, whether Cairo, AGG, Direct2D, etc are all immediate drawing APIs. There are no "objects" that you manipulate or attach labels to. You simply draw stuff in a location. If you want to move something, you have to draw the stuff in that new location.

Comment: That's unfortunate. It seems like this type of thing must have been created multiple times over, I'm suprised no-one has open-sourced it.

Comment: @AShelly What good would be served? Whatever system was developed would be inexorably bound to the underlying rendering system. If I wrote such a thing for Cairo, then you would _have_ to use Cairo to use it. There are a _lot_ of rendering systems available, whether just for different platforms or whatever. So such code would inevitably be highly specialized; suited only for the small subset of programmers who use that specific rendering system.

Comment: @NicolBolas That seems a little short sighted. Your answer says "general ease", but a high level drawing library could grow to be quite a complex system once you begin including things like animations, user interaction etc.  Re-writing these systems continually is a waste of time, and it would be nice to see more de facto standard options.  An extrapolated example is Cocos2D for iPhone, which is really just a 2D wrapper API for OpenGL ES providing support for sprites, scenes, layers, etc.  But it saves an enormous amount of development time as opposed to building a new game engine from scratch

Comment: @wallacer: Cocos2D _is_ a highly specialized system. Just because something is specialized doesn't mean that it isn't _useful_ to someone. For the particular case you're talking about (game development), it has some merit. But for the OP's use, it is far from useful. Hence the term "specialized". Also, note that Cocos2D is of no value to someone wanting to do desktop or otherwise cross-platform development. So the number of people who might use it are necessarily smaller than the number of people who develop for iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

[I use SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) for my graphics needs. I only use it for the OpenGL context (which it handles great) but it's quite friendly for getting efficient and portable graphics to work. There are software drawing routines available if you don't want to deal with OpenGL.

Comment: None of that is actually high level, which is what the user asked for.

Answer (score 0):

There is the new [Direct2D API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct2D) for Windows by Microsoft, mainly aimed at vector graphics.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps [AGG](http://www.antigrain.com/) would work for you. if you step back a few revs, you will also find a license which is better for commercial development.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with qt lib
qt is a great toolkit and multiplatform